# PDF file insertion, page breaks

Tags: pdftex, page-breaking, appendices

I would like to add a pdf file containing an article within the appendix. 
When I insert a pdf file using \includegraphics command, a page break is added. This makes the appendix chapter title appear in a page and the article in another even if I reduce the scale. 
What can I do to avoid the page break?

**Edit:** 
Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} %twoside - impréssion rectoverso
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}       
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/dad/Desktop/TexMaker/thesis/images/}} 
\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{niceframe}  
\usepackage{tkz-graph}  
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tocloft}    
%\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{thmtools}       
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\vv}{\vspace{20mm}}
\newcommand{\hs}{\hspace{10mm}}
\newcommand{\hh}{\hspace{20mm}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[theorem]
\theoremstyle{remark}   %definition, plain, remark
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$} %QED=Quod Erat Demonstrandum - End of demo
```

Here's what I've used:

```
    %Appendices
\appendix
\chapter*{\sc Appendix A}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\sc Appendix A}
\rhead{\emph{Appendix A}}

\chapter*{\sc Appendix B} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\sc Appendix B}
\rhead{\emph{Appendix B}}

\chapter*{\sc Appendix C} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\sc Appendix C}
\rhead{\emph{Appendix C}}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{tryout.pdf}
    \end{figure}
```

Here's what I get:
[image: Title + 1st page of pdf]

Comment: `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, `\includepdf{file}` if you want full-size pdf.

Comment: `\includegraphics` doesn't force a page break or do any spacing at all, if you get a page break after the chapter title then presumably the image you are including is larger than the space below the title

Comment: If you are getting a page break after the chapter title, you are probably using \includepdf (which force a new page) and not \includegraphics.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it's true, \includepdf adds a page break. But, I used \include graphics.

Comment: Probably, as @DavidCarlisle said, the image is larger than the space below the title. The image is a4 size and I've changed the scale to be 0.25 so I guess it's supposed to fit in and yet it doesn't.

Comment: Then you are doing something you didn't told yet, normally there is no page break between a chapter title and a graphic, even if the graphic is too large and moves to a new page it would pull the chapter title with it. Show a complete example.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your pdf image contains a lot of white space around it.  You can use a program such as pdfcrop to crop the image, i.e. to remove the white space, before inclusion.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have edited my post and added an example.

Comment: Well the figure environment is a float, so it naturally can float away .... Don't use it, if you don't need it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I omitted the figure environment and the page break naturally disappeared. But, why does it insert only the first page of the pdf document?

Comment: \includegraphics includes only one page. You can use \includepdf[pages=2-]{..} from the pdfpages package for the following pages. Or \includegraphics[page=2]{...}.

Comment: You should still crop your image.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer \includepdf[pages=2-]{...} works just fine but the page numbers on which the pages were inserted, mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: Probably the graphics overprints them. Use \fbox{\includegraphics ...} to see the size of the images and then crop them with trim + clip.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer using \fbox helps a lot. I then used trim and clip with \includegraphics. But then, I had to include every single page of the pdf document one by one. 
\includegraphics[page=2,trim={15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm},clip,scale=1]{pdf/olariu.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=3,trim={15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm},clip,scale=1]{pdf/olariu.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=4,trim={15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm},clip,scale=1]{pdf/olariu.pdf}
\includegraphics[page=5,trim={15mm 15mm 15mm 15mm},clip,scale=1]{pdf/olariu.pdf}